# EADDRINUSE error while listening on port 443

Tags: reactjs, nginx

My react app needs an https connection so I need to run it on port 443.

I am receiving the following error no matter what port I run my app on:

```
0|server   |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
0|server   |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
0|server   |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/fsadmin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
0|server   |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
0|server   |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
0|server   |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
0|server   |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
0|server   |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
0|server   |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
0|server   |   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
0|server   |   errno: -98,
0|server   |   syscall: 'listen',
0|server   |   address: '::',
0|server   |   port: 443
0|server   | }
```

If I specifically run it on port 443 the error is prefixed with:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::443
```

This suggests that there is a process in the background somewhere that is running on the port, however when I run the line `lsof -i :443` the output only shows info related to Nginx, which as I understand runs concurrently with my app and certainly should not be blocking any requests.

Does anyone have any ideas of what could be holding up the port? The domain I am using was previously hosted by somebody else, I wondered if there could be some issue there but I've been told that the previous host account is now inactive.

Any help or advise would be hugely appreciated. TIA

Comment: Please provide more information. What server are you using? What OS?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. I am on Windows, my site is being hosted on DigitalOcean

Comment: "the output only shows info related to Nginx, which as I understand runs concurrently with my app and certainly should not be blocking any requests." Only one process can have a given port. If `nginx` has it (listens on it), then your application can't. If your application is "behind" `nginx` then it should be running on `localhost` address basically and not `::` as seen above that means "any aka all addresses on the host".  Other than that your question is offtopic here as not really related to programming.

Comment: I see, so can you help me understand why the first error is occuring even if I run my app on say port 8000? Btw I am now in production environment

Comment: this isn't how you do production. you want to either build it and have nginx serve the files or (better) deploy to a serverless platform like vercel / netlify. This isn't next / remix, is it?

Comment: Also you can do it your way (development as production) by making a vhost in nginx and proxypass to localhost:8000. That doesn't explain why it's trying to listen on 443 though

Comment: Yes I built the app using localhost initially. Using nginx now to serve the files in deployment. Everything was working fine until I needed to switch to https

Comment: Oh I see, this is a node script. Why did you tag this with react?

Comment: Well it is a MERN stack app, but you're right, node would have been a more appropriate tag

Answer (score 0):

> so I need to run it on port 443.

You can have an https listener on any TCP port.  It's not restricted to 443.  The only thing needed is `https://` as the URL typed into the browser's address bar and a test certificate installed correctly.

`https://localhost:3000` in the address bar of your browser would successfully connect to your test server (listening on port 3000) if it was setup that way.  The problem is that you can't get easily get a signed certificate for "localhost" from any certificate providers.  You might need to create a test-only certificate, but I'm a little hazy on how to do that.

What I typically do is that I have a DNS "A" record registered for `localhost.mydomain.com` pointing to 127.0.0.1, which is always the IP address of localhost. Then I use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) in DNS challenge mode to generate a signed certificate for that DNS entry.  Then configure my test server to use that certificate. Then just type `https://localhost.mydomain.com:3000` into the address bar of the browser to test.

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually I already have an SSL certificate installed and am now working in production environment